# How to Show and Hide the menu Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see the design of this menu: http://jordanek.eu/aktual/index6.html where I made a menu (left side) which has some functionality such as when click on white bar “Vyrobce”, then a yellow bar “Vyrobce” would be appeared and white bar “Vyrobce” would be disappeared. And when click on closing link “x” on yellow bar “Vyrobce” it would be disappeared with all elements and white bar “Vyrobce” would be appeared again.

The problem is when I click anywhere on yellow bar “Vyrobce” except closing link “x”, the white bar “Vyrobce” appear again and show the both menu at a time. But I want to show only one bar at a time. How could I do it?

Can anybody help me to fix it? Thank you.

N.B. I use this javascript function for show and hide the bars which I got form: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp. You could see the whole code by visiting the given link and see the source code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#headingOne").click(function(){
                $(".panel_heading1").hide();
    });
    $("#collapseOne").click(function(){
      $(".panel_heading1").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: from using the site that panel has more problems than that. to answer your question, why not use a simple approach of toggling an active class? you don't need to create a separate header for this. just modify the existing header.

Comment: also accordions are common controls, so you should not have to reinvent it. can you use an existing one?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div `#collapseOne` you are binding close event to, wraps entire area. Instead try to bind click event to only a close link:

```
$("#collapseOne [data-toggle='collapse']").click(function() {
    $(".panel_heading1").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell the problem if we can't see the whole code but i think you are maybe applying the click event on the whole  `$("#collapseOne")` while you need just to apply it to the X link inside it.